# How do I debug a HTTP 502 error?

Tags: python, http, nginx

I have a Python Tornado server sitting behind a nginx frontend.  Every now and then, but not every time, I get a 502 error.  I look in the nginx access log and I see this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2010:18:04:02 -0400] "POST /a/question/updates HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "http://localhost/tagged/python" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
```

and in the error log:

```
2010/06/02 18:04:02 [error] 14033#0: *1700 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _,
request: "POST /a/question/updates HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/a/question/updates", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/tagged/python"
```

I don't *think* any errors show up in the Tornado log.  How would you go about debugging this?  Is there something I can put in the Tornado or nginx configuration to help debug this?

Comment: Most will find, this is the result when nginx fails to validate upstream headers (201 with content), or there are so many errors (Notices) logged that it breaks the 4k error buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line from the error log is very informative in my opinion. It says the connection was refused by the upstream, it contains client IP, Nginx server config, request line, hostname, upstream URL and referrer.

It is pretty clear you must look at the upstream (or firewall) to find out the reason.

In case you'd like to look at how Nginx processes the request, why it chooses specific server and location sections -- there is a beautiful "debug" mode. (Note, your Nginx binary must be built with debugging symbols included). Then:

```
error_log  /path/to/your/error.log debug;
```

will turn on debugging for all the requests. Debugging information in the error log requires some time to get used to interpret it, but it's worth the efforts.

*Do not use this "as is" for high traffic sites*! It generates a lot of information and your error log will grow very fast. If you need to debug requests in the production, use `debug_connection` directive:

```
events {
  debug_connection 1.2.3.4;
}
```

It turns debugging on for the specific client IP address only.