# Suddenly I am getting 502 on an End point, rest are working fine

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am serving django project with gunicorn, It running fine but after some time on one specific endpoint start giving 502. Other api end point still okay and giving proper response.

I already tried with gunicorn service settings

Current setting

```
ExecStart=/var/virtualenv/d/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 proj.wsgi:application -b :9008 --threads 8 -k gthread --timeout 120 

47.247.243.245 - - [14/Jun/2019:15:02:11 +0000] "GET /api/user/1263/league/81/ HTTP/1.1" 200 291 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
157.32.16.35 - - [14/Jun/2019:15:02:11 +0000] "GET /api/v1/xyc-leaderboard/?contest=4973 HTTP/1.1" 200 43714 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1""
157.32.16.35 - - [14/Jun/2019:15:02:16 +0000] "GET /api/v1/xy/xy-team/15543 HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
157.32.16.35 - - [14/Jun/2019:15:02:16 +0000] "GET /api/v1/xy/xy-team/15543/ HTTP/1.1" 502 5517 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"

171.76.167.124 - - [14/Jun/2019:14:39:56 +0000] "GET /api/v1/xy/xy-team/15343/ HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug a HTTP 502 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962439/how-do-i-debug-a-http-502-error)

Comment: @JulienD No Its not the same. Its only getting when we are getting good traffic for like 70-80% CPU usage for last 15-20 Mins